# How to add Image or Widget inside charts_flutter Graphs?

Tags: flutter, graph, charts

I am building a graph using flutter **[charts_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter)** library. I am following example from [This](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/gallery.html) page **Stacked** of **Bar Charts**

I could achieve output like below image without the red portion.[image]

My question is there any way to add icons or widgets inside the graph in **[charts_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter)** ?